# How to implement custom authentication with Linq to SQL and ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, authorization, custom-authentication

I am coding a Sharepoint Provider-hosted app with Linq to SQL to create the database according to database design. I need to implement authentication and authorization for my app. There is some logic involved on how the user should be authenticated/authorized:

**When the user clicks the app in SharePoint:**

1. The user's email address is read from SharePoint context.
2. App looks if user's email address is in `Accounts` table (custom database).
3. App determines, providing user was found in `Accounts` table, which Role he has in **Accounts** table.
4. Render `View` depending on user `Role`
5. If user was not found in `Accounts` table, display error message instead of redirecting to login page.

**Note**: User doesn't see LogIn page when he comes from SharePoint

**When the user calls the LogIn page url directly:**

1. Display Login Page
2. User enters credentials (E-Mail from SharePoint with Password)
3. App checks if these credentials are valid by checking the `Accounts` table.
4. If credentials are valid, check also the Role from `Accounts` table.
5. Render `View` depending on user Role.

This is the `Accounts` table:

```
**Accounts**
------------
UserName (string, SharePoint E-Mail)
Password
Role (string, value from struct)
```

This is my custom `Roles` struct:

```
public struct Roles
{
    public struct UserRoles
    {
        public const string NormalUser= "NormalUser";
        public const string PrivilegedUser = "PrivilegedUser ";
    }

    public struct AdminRoles
    {
        public const string SuperAdmin = "SuperAdmin ";
        public const string ProjectsAdmin = "ProjectsAdmin ";
        public const string UsersAdmin = "UsersAdmin ";
    }
}
```

Basically, this is what I have to work with. I am a little confused because there are so many possibilities. I don't really want to keep the roles in a custom database, so I didn't want to use a `RoleProvider`.

Comment: For anything related to ASP.NET identification, authentication and authorization, I highly recommend you to look at Identity. It's extremely customizable and very easy to use/customize.

Comment: I second ASP.NET Identity: http://www.asp.net/identity : Since the roles are used by your app, it must be done at the app database side. A rather shortcut would be to, create the roles in SharePoint itself using SharePoint Groups and verify the user membership using client context. This means your user's permissions are maintained from SharePoint and not from app.